# Finding a char's count in a String with Replace method

Tags: java, string, replace, count, char

```
String word = "abcdefg";
int a_counter = word.length() - word.replace("a", "").length();
```

This code gives me the count of 'a' in the 'word' string. But someone can explain me how it works?(Java)

Comment: its giving 1 as output which is correct. Whats wrong in that ?

Comment: @Rehman: "But someone can explain me how it works?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be clear now after adding `syso` statements.

`word.length()` - Actual length which is `7`
word.replace("a", "") - removes `a` from String `abcdefg`, so length becomes `6`, **return new String object** of length `6`

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String word = "abcdefg";
        System.out.println(word.length());
        System.out.println(word.replace("a", "").length());
        int a_counter = word.length() - word.replace("a", "").length();
        System.out.println(a_counter);
    }
```

**Output**

```
7
6
1
```

Answer (score 1):

`word.length()`gives you the number of all characters in the string.
`word.replace("a", "")` removes all 'a's from the initial string and generates a new string. The difference of the length of both is then the amount of 'a's in your initial string ...

Answer (score 0):

`word.length()` = 7 and `word.replace("a", "")` = bcdefg whose length is 6 so 7-6 =1

Answer (score 0):

The number of characters in the initial String `word`

```
word.length()
```

Create a new String by removing all occurrences of 'a' from `word`

```
word.replace("a", "")
```

The number of characters in the `word` that are not 'a'. Or what remained after removing all 'a' from `word`

```
word.replace("a", "").length()
```

The numbers of 'a' in `word`

```
word.length() - word.replace("a", "").length();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
word.length()
```

Returns the word length (Thanks Captain Obvious).

```
word.replace("a", "").length
```

Returns the length of word after deleting all 'a'.
With "abcdefg" as word, you get:

```
"abcdefg".length - "bcdefg".length
= 7 - 6
= 1
```